# Subtitle of video not working in HTML 5 video tag

Tags: html, video, html5-video, html5-audio, subtitle

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata" height='400px' width='500px'src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt" default>
   <track label="Deutsch" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt">
   <track label="Español" kind="subtitles" srclang="es" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

I have use HTMl 5 video tag. video is working fine but subtitle not working. Please guys give me any suggestion. Here is https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt caption file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" controls preload="metadata" height='400px' width='500px' src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4">
   <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt" default>
   <track label="Deutsch" kind="subtitles" srclang="de" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt">
   <track label="Español" kind="subtitles" srclang="es" src="https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @RevtiShah I have follow this guide line Please can you let me know what i have doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the error from console, you will see the message like this:

> Unsafe attempt to load URL
>   https://video-react.js.org/assets/elephantsdream/captions.en.vtt from
>   frame with URL https://stacksnippets.net/js. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

That mean the source of the video and the subtitle file must be in same location.

[image]

In your example, you're playing video on https://stacksnippets.net/js while refering the subtitle file on https://video-react.js.org. That's why the request had been blocked.

Comment: there are any ways to use another location vtt file ?

Comment: @SuhagLapani88 Nope. You cannot refer vtt file from another domain because of [cross-origin resource sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 1):

My website is at `https://www.example.org`, while video and subtitle files were hosted on `https://files.example.org`, served by MinIO (S3-compatible storage).
Both Chromium and Firefox complained that the subtitle file could not be loaded.

After adding the [`crossorigin=anonymous`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-crossorigin) attribute to the `<video>` tag it worked.